# Insert data into Database without reloading the page (PHP + Jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my code:

```
<form action='insert.php' method='post' id='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button id='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
    <script src='insert.js'></script>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' id='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button id='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
    <script src='insert.js'></script>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' id='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button id='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
    <script src='insert.js'></script>
</form>
```

Here is: `insert.js`

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$('#insert').click(function(){
    $.post(     
        $('#myform').attr('action'),
        $('#myform :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

**The Problem:**

Only the code inside first `<form></form>` tag works. If i click on `submit` button of other`<form></form>` tags, then I get re-directed to `insert.php` file.

What is the problem? If it is related to same id thing, then I would not like to add different `id`'s. for each new form

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: ID's must be unique. Maybe use Classes instead?

Comment: Sure, i have no problem in using classes. Let me try

Comment: You should have to use Ajax.

Comment: He is using AJAX @MuhammadUsman

Comment: The `name` elements should also be unique in a page.

Comment: @JayBlanchard should they be only unique within a form, rather a page (as a whole)?

Comment: @JustBaron read what it says in the link

Comment: This is not correct way to do this. You should use ajax, you should include insert.js only once, id should be unique in a page, And on click event of submit button, you should not do return false. Instead you should write an ajax funciton with e.preventDefault();

Comment: On the whole @JustBaron

Comment: They are using AJAX @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay `$.post` ***is*** an ajax method

Comment: I tried using `class`, but it is not working. This is how I replace class in Jquery code right? `$('.myform')` any syntax error?

Comment: It is more than that @Toby.

Comment: Whoever edited changes to the OP's code, don't do that as it changes the nature of the question and leaves out key information to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Assuming you load insert.js once into the page:

```
<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>
```

Once you have that done you can use a single jQuery function to handle all of the forms:

```
$(function() {
    $('.insert').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(     
            $(this).closest('.myform').attr('action'),
            $(this).closest('.myform :input').serializeArray(),
            function(result){
                $(this).closest('.myform').find('.result').html(result);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

You do have to do some DOM traversal to get the form elements related to the insert button.

1. `$(this).closest('.myform')` finds the parent of the insert button
2. `$(this)closest(.myform').find('.result')` finds the child element with the class of 'result' to add the results to.

Comment: It re-directs me to insert.php (even the first form) sir

Comment: check syntax errors

Comment: everything is correct sir

Comment: I made a mistake on syntax @Toby, on this line `$(this).closest('.myform').find('.result').html(result);` which I have now corrected.

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: Try adding `preventDefault()` as I have done in the updated code. `$('.insert').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Same problem sir

Comment: Is the code enclosed in a document ready handler?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple instances of `insert.js`

Use  common classes for all the forms and elements instead of duplication of ID's.

We can also use the submit event to post the data

HTML

```
<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform'>
  <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id' />
  <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
  <p class='result'></p>

</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform'>
  <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id' />
  <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
  <p class='result'></p>

</form>
<!-- load once per page -->
<script src='insert.js'></script>
```

JS

```
$('.myform').submit(function(){
    // `this` is the instance of myForm class the event occurred on
    var $form = $(this),
        url = $form.attr('action'),
        data = $form.serializeArray(); // or use serialize() which is more common

    $.post( url, data, function(result){
         // look inside this form instance for element to populate
         $form.find('.result').html(result);
     });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: It re-directs me to insert.php (even the first form) sir

Comment: Make sure code is wrapped in `$(function(){ /* code here */})` and check browser console for any errors thrown

Comment: Yes, it is sir.

Comment: Here's a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/nd6r20wt/1

Comment: WOW, Why it is not working with me? Make a `.html` file and copy/paste this code: https://jsfiddle.net/nd6r20wt/2/

Is it working for u?

Comment: Did you include jQuery.js and before `insert.js`? What errors do you see in your browser console?

Comment: Yes, i include, it just re-directs me to `/echo/html/`, no errors

Comment: Something else must be different. Works fine for me

Comment: It is working in fiddle, but If i copy/paste the exact same code, it do not work. Nvm, this is problem from my side, i guess

Comment: Try `alert($('.myform').length)` outside of the `submit()` .. should not be zero

Comment: This is the query, i should use right? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: The alert box echo 2. But nothing happens when i click insert

Comment: *"nothing happens"* is different than "it redirects to `insert.php`"

Comment: add a `fail()` handler to `$.post`

Comment: yes, nothing happens here. let me add

Answer (score -2):

Try something like below using jQuery Ajax:

```
$(".submit-button-class").click(function() {
  var formData = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YOUR URL",
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      //show loading image while processing
    },
    success: function(resp) {
      // do something here
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert('error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    }
  });
});
```

**Note: you should use class selector instead of id selector for submit button**

Comment: Same error as mentioned in the question. Only first form works.

Comment: @Toby please check my `Note` in answer. use class selector instead of id selector

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Same problem, if I keep this class `$(".submit-button-class")`, If i replace it with `myform` class. Even the first form redirects me to insert.php + all the forms get echo'ed again (total 6 form) before redirect

Comment: @Toby you should add `submit-button-class` to your `<button class='insert'>Insert</button>`

Comment: Now the first form also re-directs me to insert.php page

Comment: Why does the OP need to add a new class? And why can't they use the `$.post` AJAX shorthand?

Comment: I don't know how $.post works, but I will try to google it, thanks. @JayBlanchard

Comment: @Toby you're already using that function. I was asking this answerer why he wanted you to change something which works perfectly fine for your purposes.